# Spring Junit not able to load applicationContext when running maven test

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I'm converting an legacy Ant project to Maven. I'm using springframework 3.1.2 Maven 3.5.4 and Junit 4.8.2

When running one of the unitest via maven command `mvn -Dtest=ConfigTest test` will get below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [unittest/classpath?spring-common-services.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [unittest/classpath?spring-common-services.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

My `ConfigTest` class extends `TestBase` class code as below:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath：spring-common-services.xml"}) 
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestBase {
    @Autowired
    AccountDAO accountDAO;
    ...
```

Now if I change the `classpath：spring-common-services.xml` to `classpath*：spring-common-services.xml`

This applicationContext load exception will gone (Not sure whether really loaded or spring ignore it).

Then I execute `mvn -Dtest=ConfigTest test` again will get BeanCreationException detail as below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'unittest.ConfigTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
 com.common.dao.AccountDAO unittest.TestBase.accountDAO; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type 
 [com.common.dao.AccountDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as 
 autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

But this `accountDAO` already configured under `spring-common-services.xml`

```
    <bean id="accountDAO" class="com.common.dao.AccountDAOImpl">
       <description>DAO for Account</description>
       <property name="contactDAO" ref="contactDAO" />
   </bean>
```

So I suspect even I change to `classpath*：spring-common-services.xml` this file may still not loaded?

My current folder structure as below:

```
src\test\resources\spring-common-services.xml
src\test\java\unittest\TestBase.java
src\test\java\unittest\config\ConfigTest.java
```

After package able to see the `spring-common-services.xml` under `target\test-classes`

Any clue for this exception?

Comment: It is trying to search for the file in `unittest` on classpath. Have you configured this somewhere else in your application

Comment: Hi @Smie u mean it was trying to find the `spring-common-services.xml` under `target\test-classes\unittest` folder?